# Erro ao realizar Update no Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Possuo um `Teste de Integração` que realiza a atualização de um objeto no banco, para isso instancio uma nova entidade e insiro as propriedades diferentes e insiro um **Id PK Válido** entretanto ao realizar a atualização é lançado a seguinte exceção:

> {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Devido até o presente momento o objeto não estar sendo **Trackeado** pelo EF para isso alterei o mapeador para funcionar da seguinte forma:

```
using (var contexto = ContextUtils.ObtenhaContextSQLServer())
{
    using (var transacao = contexto.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {

        //Inseri para teste, Count == 0
        var antesDeAttach = contexto.Chamarizes.Local;

        //Inseri para teste
        contexto.Attach(model);

        //Inseri para teste, Count == 1
        var depoisDeAttach = contexto.Chamarizes.Local;

        contexto.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        contexto.Entry(model).Property(x => x.DataCriacao).IsModified = false;

        contexto.Update(model);
        contexto.SaveChanges();
        transacao.Commit();
    }
}
```

Inseri um **Attach** da entidade **model** antes de realizar o **Update** porém persiste a exceção, para analisar o problema, instrumentei o código com a verificação das entidades **Trackeadas** e o resultado é que sim a entidade está sendo. Qual seria a razão do problema? e possível solução?

Versões:
EF Core 2.1.1.0

Comment: Tive esse erro em dois casos: update sem passar a chave primaria(id) ou update quando o registro não existia no bd

Answer (score 0):

Quando o você tem um modelo que está desconectado do contexto (ou foi buscado por outro contexto) o Entity não tem o *Tracking* deste modelo. Nesse caso o melhor meio (ou pelo menos o que eu uso e funciona bem) é você buscar o modelo novamente e fazer o update do *modeloAlterado* para dentro do *modeloExistente*, para isso o Entity possui o método `SetValues()`.

Veja o exemplo do meu método `Save` (*fiz algumas alterações para fica mais legível*):

```
    public virtual void Save(Pessoa p)
    {
        //----- Faz verificação se entidade existe no banco
        var pessoaExistente = contexto.Pessoa.Find(p.Id);

        if (pessoaExistente != null)
        {
            contexto.Entry(pessoaExistente ).CurrentValues.SetValues(p);
            contexto.Update(p);
        }
        else
        {
            contexto.Update(p);
        }

        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
```

O método `Update` atualiza ou insere o objeto no banco de dados, porém você não pode(até onde eu pesquisei) passar o um contexto não *trackeado*, ele tentará inserir.

Eu ainda estou pesquisando sobre o comportamento desde caso para entidades relacionadas, considere que você pode ter problemas quanto a isso. Exemplo, se o modelo *Pessoa* tem uma entidade *Cidade* relacionada a ele, o Entity pode tentar inserir essa cidade ou (no caso do Update) tentar atualizá-la.

Mas espero que de uma forma geral eu possa te ajudar a achar uma solução.

*Ps. Esse código está implementado no EFCore 2.2.4*